# How can I run Qt5 GUI application on Raspbian Stretch Lite (without X)?

Tags: qt5, display, framebuffer, egl

On **Raspbian Stretch Lite**, November 2018 version,
with following **Qt5 GUI application**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QLabel label("Hello world !");
   label.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

and following project file:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Tue Mar 5 01:53:35 2019
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
QT += widgets 
TARGET = hello
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += hello.cpp
```

I've made as follows:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o hello.o hello.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o hello hello.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lpthread
```

Then, execute it, I've get following error message:

```
./hello
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted
```

Does anyone know how can I configure my Qt Gui application running on the EGL or FB directory without X? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your current Qt library is only compiled to use xcb, if you want to use eglfs you must compile Qt with that option, for more information read:
 https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

Comment: Thank you for good information! I'll try the steps on the wiki.